# What exactly would the Aurors have done with spirit-Voldemort?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, ministry-of-magic

We have it from Voldemort that the Ministry of Magic sent teams of Aurors abroad to look for him after his demise at Godric's Hollow.

> "I could possess the bodies of others. But I dared not go where other humans were plentiful, for I knew that the Aurors were still abroad and searching for me."
>   <sub>*(Goblet of Fire, Chapter 33, The Death Eaters)*.</sub>

My question is simply **what would they have done with him if they had found him?**

They are Aurors. Ghostbusters they are not. The Aurors could hardly do much to Voldemort when he didn't have a body. As I've said on [another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125935/why-didnt-dumbledore-act-more-decisively-in-response-to-trelawneys-second-prop), spirit-Voldemort could simply swoosh away when they confront him. What kind of threat do they pose to him that would make him hide from them? And if they knew they couldn't harm him, what explains the decision to send 
in the Auror hit-squads?

Comment: If they had a basilisk, they could probably petrify him.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh. I'm sure the Ministry of Magic keeps a fully trained and compliant Basilisk around for just these sorts of situations.

Comment: Well (a) they probably wouldn't know *until* they found him (b) did a lot of people really know he was a ghost, or they just knew something about Potter backfired? and (c) he's still a danger no matter what, and that's what Aurors handle.

Comment: Shove him through the veil and see what happens

Comment: We know that the Ministry can restrain ghosts (they did it with Myrtle) but Voldemort isn't a ghost. We know that you can petrify a ghost, but again, he ain't a ghost.

Comment: It is obvious from the quote that Voldemort, at least, believed they could harm him.  I see no reason to think him wrong about that.  If you want to know what specific spell(s) they might use, I doubt that information is in the books - seeing as the situation never came up - but I guess someone might know of an answer on Pottermore or elsewhere.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what "swoosh away" is supposed to mean, or what evidence there is to support that statement. Is there any reason to believe that Voldemort had access to any means of travelling great distances or at speed in his "less than ghost" form?

Comment: @Anthony Grist: He hid in Albania, so he was able to travel there from Godric’s Hollow, quite a long distance. We don’t know how much time it took him to get there, however.

Comment: Perhaps how the Aurors treat Credence Barebone is a clue? (Trying to avoid spoilers but their attempts seemed quite effective and I can imagine the situations are somewhat similar)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think a clue comes from this line from Voldemort:

> "I sometimes inhabited animals — snakes, of course, being my
> preference — but I was little better off inside them than as pure
> spirit, for their bodies were ill adapted to perform magic . . . and
> my possession of them shortened their lives; none of them lasted long.
> . . ."
>
> —Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire

Assuming the Aurors could somehow track Voldemort's spirit (maybe that have a spell like "Spiritus Triangulum" that lets them know a general direction and how close they are), the obvious approach would be to catch Voldemort in animal form, then stun the animal and then bind it, keep it asleep, or otherwise incapacitate it so that it is not dead, but also so that Voldemort does not have an opportunity to leave its body.

Once captured and in this state, they might just make sure that he stayed this way indefinitely, perhaps with a round the clock guard and periodic refreshments of whatever enchantments are keeping Voldemort asleep, until perhaps some better plan can be devised - for instance, maybe throw the animal body through the Veil in the Ministry or something.

Comment: A good stab at a tough question!